# How to make the width of a container match its height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `Container` which has a height based on its parent which is an `Expanded` with a flex of 2. I need the height and the width to be the same. I don't want to create a fixed width such as `width: 100.0`. Is it possible to make the width match the height of this `Container` inside an `Expanded`?

Comment: use `AspectRatio`

Comment: @CopsOnRoad it is designed for such cases: *"A widget that attempts to size the child to a specific aspect ratio."*

Comment: @pskink I thought I should include it in my solution but someone answered it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you'll have to use `LayoutBuilder`, here is the minimal code:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      flex: 2,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (_, constraints) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            width: constraints.maxHeight, // width is made equal to height
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 9,
      child: Container(color: Colors.orange),
    ),
  ],
)
```

---

Edit: As @pskink and other mentioned you can also use `AspectRatio`

```
AspectRatio(
  aspectRatio: 1,
  child: Container(color: Colors.blue),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Aspect Ratio will work**

```
AspectRatio(
       aspectRatio: 1,
       child: Container(
         color: Colors.red,
       ),
     )
```